# A simple if/else bash script which reacts to user's yes/no input?

Tags: bash, shell

I basically have a bash script which executes 5 commands in a row. I want to add a logic which asks me "Do you want to execute command A" and if I say YES, the command is executed, else the script jumps to another line and I see the prompt "Do you want to execute command B".

The script is very simple and looks like this

```
echo "Running A"
commandA &
sleep 2s;
echo "done!"

echo "Running B"
commandB &
sleep 2s;
echo "done!"
...
```

Comment: why are you using `&` and sleeping there? you should run it synchronously...

Comment: @cha0site I am starting some external development tool and without & the tool will start only the first command

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use the [`read`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read) builtin to get input from the user.

```
read -p "Run command $foo? [yn]" answer
if [[ $answer = y ]] ; then
  # run the command
fi
```

Put the above into a [function](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/functions.html) that takes the command (and possibly the prompt) as an argument if you're going to do that multiple times.

Comment: I does not work with double [[ brackets, but it works with single [ bracket.

Comment: It really should work with `[[`. Are you sure you're using `bash`, with `#! /bin/bash` as the first line of your script?

Comment: there is no `#! /bin/bash` on the first line. I guess that may be the problem as I did not explicitly said it's bash.

Comment: @sandalone the spaces between `[[` and `$` and `;` matter in some ridiculous way, I found,..

Answer (score 1):

You want the Bash [read builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins). You can perform this in a loop using the implicit *REPLY* variable like so:

```
for cmd in "echo A" "echo B"; do
    read -p "Run command $cmd? "
    if [[ ${REPLY,,} =~ ^y ]]; then
        eval "$cmd"
        echo "Done!"
    fi
done
```

This will loop through all your commands, prompt the user for each one, and then execute the command only if the first letter of the user's response is a Y or y character. Hope that helps!

Comment: You might want to try to avoid `eval` if you can. One idea would be to encapsulate each command in a function which either describes itself or runs itself depending on how you invoke it.

Comment: The lowercase parameter expansion `${,,}` requires Bash 4. And see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).